Can't supply assets to Compound via call Solidity
I have Smart Contract
I make two functions supplyLiquidity with call opcode and supplyLiquidity1 where using interface instead
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import {IERC20} from "@chainlink/contracts-ccip/src/v0.8/vendor/openzeppelin-solidity/v4.8.3/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import {IComet} from "./interfaces/IComet.sol";
import {SafeERC20} from "@chainlink/contracts-ccip/src/v0.8/vendor/openzeppelin-solidity/v4.8.3/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";


contract MarketInteractions {
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;
    address payable owner;

   address public immutable POOL;

    address private immutable usdcAddress =
        0x1c7D4B196Cb0C7B01d743Fbc6116a902379C7238;
    IERC20 private usdc;

    event SEE(bytes data);

    constructor(address _addressProvider) {
        POOL = _addressProvider;
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
        usdc = IERC20(usdcAddress);
        usdc.safeApprove(_addressProvider, type(uint256).max);
    }

    function supplyLiquidity(address _tokenAddress, uint256 _amount) external {
        address asset = _tokenAddress;
        uint256 amount = _amount;


        bytes memory message = abi.encodeCall(
            IComet.supply,
            (
                asset,
                amount
            )
        );

        //IComet comet = IComet(POOL);
        //comet.supply(asset, amount);

        (bool success, bytes memory data) = POOL.call(message);

        if (success) {
            emit SEE(data);
        }
    }

    function supplyLiquidity1(address _tokenAddress, uint256 _amount) external {
        address asset = _tokenAddress;
        uint256 amount = _amount;


        bytes memory message = abi.encodeCall(
            IComet.supply,
            (
                asset,
                amount
            )
        );

        IComet comet = IComet(POOL);
        comet.supply(asset, amount);
    }


    function approveusdc(uint256 _amount, address _poolContractAddress)
        external
        returns (bool)
    {
        return usdc.approve(_poolContractAddress, _amount);
    }

    function allowanceusdc(address _poolContractAddress)
        external
        view
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return usdc.allowance(address(this), _poolContractAddress);
    }

    function getBalance(address _tokenAddress) external view returns (uint256) {
        return IERC20(_tokenAddress).balanceOf(address(this));
    }

    function withdraw(address _tokenAddress) external onlyOwner {
        IERC20 token = IERC20(_tokenAddress);
        token.transfer(msg.sender, token.balanceOf(address(this)));
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(
            msg.sender == owner,
            "Only the contract owner can call this function"
        );
        _;
    }

    receive() external payable {}
}

After calling supplyLiquidity it doesn't change anything

But supplyLiquidity1 work and i don't know why first function with call doesn't work


Can you provide the code for IComet interface in your question?

Also, please provide the POOL contract address as well as the implementation of the supply() function. It would be great, if you can share all of that by pushing to a GitHub repo and attach the link of the same in your question.

Here is github repo - https://github.com/AHAHHAHAHAHAHAHAHHA/problem/tree/main
Also i used 0xAec1F48e02Cfb822Be958B68C7957156EB3F0b6e for POOL in sepolia testnet

Both supplyLiquidity() and supplyLiquidity1() functions are working fine though. You can check the balanceOf function by passing your MarketInteractions contract address. The balance is getting increased depending on the calculation using the amount you've passed, while calling supplyLiquidity as well as supplyLiquidity1.

Still not worked for me, after calling balanceOf with my contract address get 0. I'm trying to view logs and seen that tx out of gas https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/sepolia/0x9c1b634c2754a31e8f7fa88eaa976986e81f73c2e858dba5f4b627dfd4e6af04/debugger?trace=0.0.0.2.0.15

Can you share a screen-recording of the process that you’re doing, with the exact values of the parameters that you’re passing?

Hi again, so i resolve issue, problem was in gas limit. Thank you for your help anyway

Hello Victor, it would be great if you can add the same as an answer too, with some explanation. So that, it might help others who would face a similar problem.
